# Reference Meta options in model

Tags: python, django

I can't reference Meta Ordering option in model as it pops up error message

> "type object 'ProductImage' has no attribute 'Meta'".

Can anyone help to fix this because as per design strategy I have to reference Meta on many occasions for this project. I just need to be able to reference Meta option in ProductImage model.

Following is the ProductImage model (cut down):

```
class ProductImage(models.Model):

    product = models.ForeignKey(
        'catalogue.Product', related_name='images', verbose_name=_("Product"))    

    display_order = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        _("Display order"), default=0,
        help_text=_("An image with a display order of zero will be the primary"
                    " image for a product"))

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["display_order"]
```

Following is the Product model (cut down):

```
class Product(models.Model):    
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(_("Date created"), auto_now_add=True)

    objects = ProductManager()
    browsable = BrowsableProductManager()
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date_created']


    def primary_image(self):
        images = self.images.all()
        ordering = self.images.model.Meta.ordering #This is where it causes issue.
        if not ordering or ordering[0] != 'display_order':
            images = images.order_by('display_order')
        try:
            return images[0]
        except IndexError:
            if self.is_child:
                return self.parent.primary_image
            else:
                return {
                    'original': self.get_missing_image(),
                    'caption': '',
                    'is_missing': True}
```

Traceback:

```
Template error:
In template C:\Users\Alikhan\supermarekt\market\static\templates\catalogue\partials\product.html, error at line 11
   type object 'ProductImage' has no attribute 'Meta'

1   {% load reviews_tags %}
2   {% load thumbnail %}
3   {% load i18n %}
4   {% load display_tags %}
5   {% load staticfiles %}
6   
7   {% block product %}
8       <article class="product_pod">
9           {% block product_image %}
10              <div class="image_container">
11  

      {% with image=product.primary_image %}       


12                      {% thumbnail image.original "x155" upscale=False as thumb %}
13                      <a href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}"><img src="{{ thumb.url }}" alt="{{ product.get_title }}" class="thumbnail"></a>
14                      {% endthumbnail %}
15                  {% endwith %}
16              </div>
17          {% endblock %}
18  
19          {% block product_review %}
20              {% iffeature "reviews" %}
21                  <p class="star-rating {{ product.rating|as_stars }}">
```

Comment: tyr  `Product._meta`

Comment: `_meta` should work instead of `Meta`

Comment: can you check replaceing `ordering = self.images.model.Meta.ordering #This is where it causes issue.` with ` ordering = self.images.model._meta.ordering #This is where it causes issue.` try if this works

Comment: I tried using _meta instead of Meta but now it says "'module' object has no attribute 'symlink'".

Comment: Where do you get this latest error?

Comment: Same place where I was trying before. Like adding products from backend.

Answer (score 0):

The way you're using it doesn't require you to access the meta options. Regardless of the meta option, you *want* to order by display order so just do that

```
images = self.images.all()
ordering = self.images.model.Meta.ordering 
if not ordering or ordering[0] != 'display_order':
    images = images.order_by('display_order')
```

should just be

```
images = self.images.order_by('display_order')
```

Comment: Can you kindly improve your answer? Because the original question or problem was that I was not able to reference "ordering" from another model. Also I can't figure out what difference you've proposed except using "self". It didn't worked though. I hate to down vote so please give it another try.

Comment: @Alikhan - The original problem was that you were trying to reference the meta option directly when you really don't need to, all you're trying to do is order images by display order in a roundabout way - so I just combined your 4 lines into 1 line; and "it didn't worked though" isn't a very helpful description.

Comment: It is causing the same issue. Also I am doing more in the function than referencing. Still what you proposed I tried already. Thanks for help I appreciate it.